# Counting Lines(PVC Cards) with Open CV

Tags: raspberry-pi, counting

I look for a starting step to count PVC cards(let's say credit cards) with Open CV. I thought that it's possible to count lines when many cards stand as contiguous. My idea to develop this project with rasperry pi to develop a portable device. I'm very new at open cv. What could be your advices? Are there any ready solution?

Comment: what have you already try ? please show some code and test cases.

Comment: I have looked for counting lines with open cv but i couldn't find a proper source. I know that it's not right mentality to wait a sample code here. I just need some advices to "start such project". As you know there are more than 2000 functions at open cv. Which functions are right for suc project? Or what are other advices?